# Android - Do job onClick Notification?

Tags: android, notifications

How can on i process specific method when i press on notification without open activity while application is opened by user?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("frame", 1);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

Answer (score 3):

You ask how to read your extras from intent? You should implement `onNewIntent()` in your activity and handle incoming Intent there. If you got more code that handles intent content then it's good to make it separate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    dealWithIntentData(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  dealWithIntentData(intent); 
}

protected void dealWithIntentData(Intent intent) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different `PendingIntent` depending on what you need to do. In your snippet you are starting an activity by calling

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You can start a service by calling
`PendingIntent.getService()`, or send a broadcast by calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

More specifically to your question, if you don't want to be depended on any activities, try sending a Broadcast (with getBroadcast) and execute any logic on the Broadcast's onReceive()

More info @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but maybe do you want to make a broadcast Receiver & handle some action in it?
You can use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` method for that.
So, using broadcast you can start activity from receiver, or, if receiver is inside activity, handle something

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("frame", 1);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    int frame = intent.getIntExtra("frame", 0);
    // TODO your code...
}
```